# How to use WCF RIA SERVICES with WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I want to use WCF RIA SERVICES in my WPF application.

but WCF RIA SERVICES client only surport silverlight and ASP.NET now, how can I use it in WPF application?

Comment: Brad Abrams did a blog on it a while back, I don't know how much has changed in the beta though. [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/17/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-8-wcf-based-data-source.aspx) - RIA services blogs series [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/08/02/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-summary.aspx).

Comment: I try to look for some informations earlier, but there is no samples about WPF use WCF RIA SERVICES.

And I have send him a Email, but it seems too busy to response me.

Comment: There's a sample app that you can download in his blog if that helps but I'm far from a RIA Services expert.

Comment: I've done a complete sample consuming the SOAP endpoint of WCF RIA Services from a WPF Applications (handling also the authentication cookie for authenticated calls) : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx Hope it helps. Regards, David Rousset

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do client-side validation in WPF using WCF RIA Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798631/how-do-i-do-client-side-validation-in-wpf-using-wcf-ria-services)

Comment: Honestly, from experience, I think WCF RIA services are unwieldy and will ultimately cause you  more problems than they solve.  Try using a simple REST-based web framework, such as ServiceStack.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link describe the RIA servicive for WPF application
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx
I think this is useful for you

Comment: possibility to access RIA domain service by soap or so is well known. the problem is actually in the lack of RIA features in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use RIA Services toolkit. It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19663).
After installing it, you can expose JSON, SOAP endpoints for your Domain Service. You can also use RIA Service with ASP.NET Dynamic data if you have the toolkit.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but this toolkit was designed to work with Silverlight environment mostly and not other environments. It would be awesome if you could provide any sample code of this toolkit being used in other scenarios. Thanks