# WPF and WCF Ria Services

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf-ria-services

Are there scenarios, where it makes sense to use **WPF** together with **WCF RIA services**?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know WPF does not **support** RIA services. You **should** really really use WCF Data Services.

See this article:
http://jack.ukleja.com/wcf-data-services-vs-wcf-ria-services/

Related SO question:
[How to use WCF RIA SERVICES with WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551258/how-to-use-wcf-ria-services-with-wpf-application)

Hope that helps! =)