# wcf linq tutorial

Tags: wpf, wcf, linq

Building a WPF XBAP based application, I need to access data in my hosted SQLServer DB (Shared hosting).

Therefore I need to create a WCF LINQ based service.

Anyone knows of a simple end-to-end tutorial demonstrating how to build the service and install it on the hosted webserver?

I've found several but either they are ASP.NET or Silverlight dedicated, either they are far from comprehensive...

Please do not answer with ASP.NET solutions... I need WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use WCF to access SQL server?

Comment: Because when running a WPF XBAP project from within a browser, it refuses to query the server, asking for certificates or authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **RIA Services** for your scenario (calling the services from WPF rather than Silverlight).

See this StackOverflow question for references on how to call RIA Services from WPF: [How to use WCF RIA SERVICES with WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551258/how-to-use-wcf-ria-services-with-wpf-application)